# clarification on axiom of regularity

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am having difficulty understanding the axiom of regularity (or foundation axiom). From what I read, the axiom of regularity ensures that given any non-empty set $x$, we won't have $x \in x$.

In terms of first-order logic, the axiom of regularity says that for any non-empty set $x$, an element $y \in x$ exists such that:

$$
\exists y(y \in x \wedge y \cap x = \emptyset)
$$

However, suppose that we define $x$ as an infinite set $x = \{x,\emptyset, a, b, c, ...\}$ where $\emptyset,a,b,c...\in x$. If I set $y=\emptyset$, we have $y \in x$, since $\emptyset$ is an element of $x$. At the same time, we have $y\cap x = \emptyset$ since $y=\emptyset$. It follows that with $y=\emptyset$, we get to meet the conditions of the axiom ... However, in this case, we also have $x \in x$ which, from my understanding, is an event that is supposed to be ruled out by the axiom of regularity.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: The "definition" $x = \{ x , \emptyset \}$ is wrong... Assume that $x$ is not empty and let $a \in x$; then we have $a \in x$ but $a \notin \{ x , \emptyset \}$ and thus by Extensionality: $x \ne \{ x , \emptyset \}$.

Comment: The issue is that $x$ and $\{ x, \emptyset \}$ are not the same: the second one has **only two** elements, whatever the first one is.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, okay but for instance, isn't the definition $x = \{x\}$ supposed to be valid (i.e. used as an example in Russell's paradox as a set containing itself). In this case, let $a \in x$, but $a \not \in \{x\}$

Comment: $x \in \{ x \}$ and thus - if we assume that $x = \{ x \}$ - we have that $x \in x$, contrary to Regularity. Thus, IF we assume Regularity, we have to conclude that $x \ne \{ x \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, okay thanks ... I modified my question a bit so that $x$ is infinite

Comment: There are other than $\mathsf {ZFC}$ versions of set theory, called [Non-wellfounded Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/) where *object circularity* (object is taken to be part of itself) is allowed. In this case, Regularity, (aka:[Foundation axiom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/#2) ) does not hold.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, okay thanks again ... does this mean that the infinite set $x$ that I wrote above also violates the Axiom of extensionality under ZFC ?

Comment: If you assume  existence of any $x=\{x,  ...\}$, regardless of what "$...$"is, you are assuming negation of Regularity, because the Pairing axiom then implies the existence of $z=\{x\}$,and the set $z$ violates Regularity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very common mistake that people tend to make. Let me make it more obvious to you.

> We define the real number $x=x+1$, then $0=x-x=(x+1)-x=1$, and therefore $0=1$.

The mistake, of course, is by thinking that the power of the word is so strong that by writing down an equation it has a solution. You wrote $x=\dots$, that is merely writing an equation, but now you still need to prove that this equation has a solution.

It is true, that in most cases that one runs into in the context of set theory, especially in the introductory and naive cases, every equation has a solution. But this is only because we tend to focus on "use" rather than "limitations". Nevertheless, $R=\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ is an equation, and we often see that it has no solutions, but since it's not phrased in this way, but rather dressed in some other fashion, we usually fail to see it for what it is.

So. Going back to your equation, $x=\{x,\varnothing,a,b,\dots\}$. If it had a solution, then defining $y=\{x\}$ which we can prove to exist using the Axiom of Pairing, or Replacement, or Power Set + Separation, we get that the elements of $y$ all have a non-empty intersection with it.

Note that it didn't even matter that $x$ was infinite. If your argument is that $\varnothing$ has an empty intersection with $x$, then what do $a,b,\dots$ even have to play in this game? Why not just take $x=\{x,\varnothing\}$?

If the answer to that is that you cannot envision such a finite set, then the real solution here is to understand why, and apply that to the infinite set as well. And of course, the real issue is not with $x$, but rather all the sets that we can create using $x$.

Comment: thanks for this answer, explaining it in such a marvelously great way!

Comment: @Asaf Do I understand this correctly ? Suppose $x$ exists under ZFC, by the Axiom of Pairing, we get $y=\{x\}$. Here, the only element of $y$ is $x$.  But since $x \in x$ from the way $x$ is defined, we get a violation of the Axiom of Regularity... Therefore this $x$ is not valid under ZFC.

Comment: @LinkL: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Regarding the assumption  of a solution, a high-school contest (multiple-choice) Q was : If $x^{x^{x^{...}}}=2$ (an infinite tower of $x$'s) then $x=?$ The solution is that $x^2=2$ so $x=\sqrt 2$. BUT  what if  $y^{y^{y^{...}}}=4$? Then $y^4=4$ so $y=\sqrt 2 =x$. Therefore $2=x^{x^{x^{...}}}=y^{y^{y^{...}}}=4.$